# Something lighter than nHibernate

Tags: c#, database, nhibernate

I want to develop a C# <-> Database application. I've considered using a ORM creating me classes for transparent access to whatever database I want to connect to.

I found **nHibernate**. But this seems very heavy and complicated to configure.

My question: Is something out there that is lighter than nHibernate?

Thanks,
Andre

Edit: Love your answers. Nearly want to mark everyone as my favourite :)

Comment: If you find NHibernate "heavy" and "complicated" maybe you should consider an alternative profession.

Comment: As Pierre Mengal said: For litte applications its too heavy.

Comment: More opinions on .NET ORMs available here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql/

Comment: I've now found what i've searched for: http://opf3.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the easiest ones I've used is http://www.subsonicproject.com/

Answer (score 5):

You may take a look at [Linq to Entities](http://naspinski.net/post/Getting-started-with-Linq-To-Entities.aspx) which integrates nicely with Visual Studio.

Comment: There is a significant difference between the first and second versions of Entity Framework (aka LinqToEntities).  I cannot recommend the first version (VS 2008 SP1/.NET 3.5) at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at this set of posts ["Build Your Own Data Access Layer"](http://davybrion.com/blog/2009/08/build-your-own-data-access-layer-series/) - it ends up building a lightweight ORM (and was written by one of the nHibernate contributers, [Davy Brion](http://davybrion.com/blog/)).

From microsoft there are [`EF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723.aspx) (entity framework) and [`Linq2Sql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx), though not sure that EF constitutes lightweight. See [this](http://ayende.com/blog/archive/2010/01/05/nhibernate-vs.-entity-framework-4.0.aspx) comparison of EF and nHibernate (biased, as the writer is a heavy nHibernate contributor).

Comment: I don't think agatha is an ORM. It's a RRSL for .net

Comment: @lomaxx - quite right. I was thinking about his "Build Your Own DAL" blogs. I thought he released it as "agatha". Answer updated and corrected.

Answer (score 2):

I found [Lightspeed](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/lightspeed/) really easy to configure and use (much quicker than nHibernate).  The express edition is limited to 8 mapped entities though so it is likely to cost you some money.

Answer (score 0):

nHibernate is not complicated to configure. But I agree that it's sometimes too much for simple applications.

When I don't use nHibernate, I use simple ADO.NET objects.

When I don't use nHibernate, it's because ORM will be counter productive.